# How to refer the foriegnkey which is an identity column in ASP.Net WebAPI models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

This is how my ASP.Net REST Web API models looks like and their DataTransferObject models are just a replica of these models without any attributes. I didn't mention ModelDto classes since they look very similar to Models. And I want to populate the database with Entity Framework  Code First approach in c#.

```
        class Customer
        {
            public int id { get; set; } // this an identity column in db

            public string name { get; set; }

            public string UserId { get; set; }

            public string Source { get; set; }

            public DateTime RegisteredOn { get; set; }
        }

        // Note: Other than identity column , The combinmation of UserId and Source is unique.

        class Ticket
        {
            public int id { get; set; }   // this an identity column in db and its ticketid which is unique

            [ForeignKey("Customer")]
            public int id { get; set; } // i am thinking this should refer the identity column of the Customer class since its unique. but if i refer the foreign key as "id" , then i will have two properties in this class one for its own identity column and other one referring to the Customer class.

            public string Description { get; set; } // ticket problem description

            public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        }


        class TicketComment
        {
             public int id { get; set; }   // this an identity column in db and its commentid which is unique

             [ForeignKey("Ticket")]
             public int id { get; set; } // i am thinking this should refer the identity column of the Ticket class since its unique. but if i refer the foreign key as "id" , then i will have two properties in this class one for its own identity column and other one referring to the tTicket class.


             public string Comment { get; set; } // user may add a comment or notes to existing ticket to provide more info or asking for status     

        }

        class TicketUpdates
        {
            public int id { get; set; }   // this an identity column in db and its updateid which is unique

            [ForeignKey("Ticket")]
            public int id { get; set; } // i am thinking this should refer the identity column of the Ticket class since its unique. but if i refer the foreign key as "id" , then i will have two properties in this class one for its own identity column and other one referring to the tTicket class.


            public string Status { get; set; } // agent may add a status to existing ticket along with some notes

        }
```

i have three questions here:

How do i refer to the identity column of the other table/entity when the current table or entity already has an identity column with the same name.( Since i am using Entity framework it always create a table with the identity column name as "id".)

And how do we retrieve the Customer records along with   each customer's tickets, each ticket's comments and each ticket's updates in one get call in REST Web API ? How should my GET method look like in **CustomerController** ?

Should I look at other fields than identity column field to refer the foreign keys ?

I looked at some of the existing posts but my scenario looks a bit different.

Comment: `public int CustomerId { get; set; }` etc.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for your reply. Then how can I modify the Get method of Customer Controller to retrieve the tickets data ,comments data ?